# how to change state of dynamically created button in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to create mqtt app in flutter.
One of feature - is ability to add new device.
Basically, app need ability to control and monitor devices.
So i trying create functionality to dynamically created buttons to control devices.

```
  _create_button(String topic, String on, String off) {
  String id = uuid.v4();
  print('create button $id');

  buttons_switches[id] = true;
  Widget _button =  ElevatedButton(
      style: style,
      onPressed: () {
        publist_button_onpress (topic, on, off, id);
      },

      child:
          Row( mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text('$topic хз'),
                Icon(Icons.circle, color: _colors),
              ]
          )
      );
  return _button;
}
```

I create button dynamically, and then add this button to array of buttons I want to show

```
 Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: buttons_dynamic,
      )
```

this buttons actually worked, but there is one prblem: i dont know how change state of this buttons
For example, change color of button from green to red

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

To change states in flutter is better use the **[setState](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/setState.html)** method. To use it, your class have to be **[StatefulWidget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulWidget-class.html)**. Once you've change the values with setStates and passed by parameters in yor method. To change for example. the color.. In ElevatedButton use ButtonStyle. Your method will be see like this.

```
  _create_button(String topic, String on, String off, Color yourColor,) {
String id = uuid.v4();
print('create button $id');

buttons_switches[id] = true

Widget _button =  ElevatedButton(
    style: ButtonStyle(   //use ButtonStyle to change the visual properties to your button
      padding: MaterialStateProperty.all(EdgeInsets.all(12)),
      elevation: MaterialStateProperty.all(0), //shows a shadow in your button
      backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(yourColor),
      shape: MaterialStateProperty.all(RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50)),
      ),
    ),
    onPressed: () {
      publist_button_onpress (topic, on, off, id);
    },

    child:
    Row( mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text('$topic хз'),
          Icon(Icons.circle, color: _colors),
        ]
    )
);
return _button;
}
```

Hope I've helped. Greetings.